# How to send an JSONArray without the key 'values'

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

My API is:

```
public interface API {

    @PUT("pedido/{lanche}")
    Observable<OrderResponseVO> createOrder(@Path("lanche") Integer lanche, @Body AddOrderRequestVO request);

}
```

I have this POJO used as body of my Retrofit PUT request:

```
public class AddOrderRequestVO {

    @SerializedName("extras")
    public JSONArray itens;it

}
```

I am receiving this body in my server:

`{ extras: { values: [ 2, 2, 2 ] } }`

but i need this:

`{ extras: [ 2, 2, 2 ] }`

how do this?

Comment: Can't you just parse the JSON, then process the structure?

Comment: The idea of retrofit + gson is abstract this process.

Comment: Instead of initializing the Object with `extra`, initialize it with `values`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JSONArray, instead use a normal Array

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public JSONArray itens;
```

with

```
public List<Integer> itens;
```

Or a list of whatever type you need to serialize to and from the json. It will give you the result you want in the JSON and it will be much easier to work with in your java code. GSON will handle the conversion from JSONArray in the JSON to list without you needing to do anything.